# No control on auto formatting in CVS diff, IntelliJ IDEA after 2019.2 version

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, intellij-idea-2020

First for all thanks for an unique and amazing product in IDE world. 
I'm struggling with a major issue of auto rearranging the imports (Remember it's not about checking the format option before commit, IDEA Provide a check box to chose for format the code before chekin)
I'll tell u steps,
Make changes into your java code, Change the order of imports. (assume another dev is using eclipse or u can say it's very old file and formatted accordingly in old format)

Now, try to revert (compare and fix like we do in merging left->right) the modified file.

U'll see that your imports has been already re-arranged to IDEA Default reformatting style. Now try apply changes from left to right, assuming we are reverting line by line. after a second, u'll see that code again re formats the imports. 
This is very annoying and my Entire team is facing issue due to this.

This is happens after 2019.2 Version of IntelliJ Idea Ultimate

Comment: Does it help if you disable [on-the-fly imports optimization](https://i.imgur.com/uNjIMcm.png)?

Comment: @CrazyCoder  Man, U made my life again. !!! It was there always? or It's just added in later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable the option to optimize the imports on the fly:

[image: optimize on the fly]

This option has been there for many years.